# Simple Quiz Website using GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I is there any free/open source project available, which creates a simple quiz on the google app engine Plattform?

The reason I ask for, and not code it myself is, that I need this quiz in one week for an exam and want to learn and fill the quiz with other people...

I very much appreaciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/quizlink/

Comment: is there a probably a much nicer looking solution;)))

Comment: Free/opensource and "nicer" don't always go together. It's function over design usually. You could always just download the source code and make it look nicer if it's important. I don't know if you're going to find something that looks nice and is opensource running on Google App Engine. If you just need a quiz, there are plenty of available quiz making websites.